# No module named x.urls

Tags: python, django

Seem to be having a problem here. Been working off my netbook for a while and brought all my code across to my desktop. Now, I'm getting 'No module named x.urls' on every single page. I don't know why. Works fine on the netbook. All I did was copy and paste all the code across. Also, I'm running 1.2.1 on the netbook and moved across to 1.3 on the desktop. Using DevServer on Debian Testing. Anything I'm missing here?

Everything is in the one urls.py file at the project root. Pastebin: http://paste2.org/p/1419080

My Settings.py (obviously in project root): http://paste2.org/p/1419084

Anything else I should post?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the directory where you put you project 'x' and it will work.

Comment: Thanks so much. Ha, bit of a noobish mistake there!